# IMU 9250 and RTIMULib on Raspberry Pi Zero W

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm using the IMU 9250 with a raspberry pi zero w. It's running the latest version of wheezy, and I'm using RTIMULib2 to read data from the IMU. I have all the necessary programs installed and I've calibrated the IMU, it's using a Kalman algorithm to get accurate data. Here is the code I'm trying to run:

```
`#!/usr/bin/python3
from math import degrees
from time import sleep
import RTIMU
SETTINGS_FILE = "/home/pi/displacedRealityDrone/IMU/RTEllipsoidFit/RTIMULib.ini"
s = RTIMU.Settings(SETTINGS_FILE)
imu = RTIMU.RTIMU(s)
if (not imu.IMUInit()):
  print("IMU init failed")
  exit(1)
else:
  print("IMU init succeeded")
imu.setSlerpPower(0.02)
imu.setGyroEnable(True)
imu.setAccelEnable(True)
imu.setCompassEnable(True)
poll_interval = imu.IMUGetPollInterval()
while True:
  data = imu.getIMUData()
  fusionPose = data["fusionPose"]
  global roll, pitch, yaw
  roll = degrees(fusionPose[0])
  pitch = degrees(fusionPose[1])
  yaw = degrees(fusionPose[2])
  print(str(roll) + "   " + str(pitch) + "   " + str(yaw))
  sleep(0.2)`
```

This is what it outputs:

```
IMU init succeeded
0.0   0.0   0.0
0.0   0.0   0.0
0.0   0.0   0.0
0.0   0.0   0.0
0.0   0.0   0.0
0.0   0.0   0.0
0.0   0.0   0.0
0.0   0.0   0.0
0.0   0.0   0.0
0.0   0.0   0.0
```

It never changes, no how much the IMU is moved. What is the issue here? Is it a bad cable? I've switched out the IMU and it gave the same result so it's not a problem with the actual chip. Is my code wrong? I've used similar code before so I don't think so, but maybe I've made a stupid mistake somewhere. Any help with this would be appreciated, I'm willing to try anything at this point.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who encounters a similar problem, this code works great, but its missing one single line that was causing it to output nothing but zeros. Fix the end of the code by changing it to this:

```
 while True:
  if imu.IMURead():
    data = imu.getIMUData()
    fusionPose = data["fusionPose"]
    global roll, pitch, yaw
    roll = degrees(fusionPose[0])
    pitch = degrees(fusionPose[1])
    yaw = degrees(fusionPose[2])
    print(str(roll) + "   " + str(pitch) + "   " + str(yaw))
    sleep(0.2)`
```